# Installing python packages on a Chromebook in Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, installation, pip, chromebook

I'm trying to install a python package (specifically pandas) into Visual Studio code on a chromebook's linux virtual machine. I've tried many different things but none of them seem to work: trying to use `pip install pandas` results in `bash: pip: command not found`. I have no idea where the actual python interpreter is located, so I can't go to the source. I thought it was that I wasn't using the correct terminal, but the only other option is `JavaScript Debug Terminal`. What am I doing wrong? Is it even possible?

Comment: You need to install python3-pip first. Here is a tutorial on how to do it: https://www.linuxmadesimple.info/2020/11/how-to-install-python-3-on-chromebook.html

Answer (score 0):

Pip is a python package management tool, which provides the functions of finding, downloading, installing and uninstalling Python packages. However, this tool is not included in the system and needs to be installed manually. Here is the official [website](https://pypi.org/project/pip/) of PIP, which contains installation instructions.